# wxWindow auto fit to parent window size

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

How can I make `wxGrid` (it inherits after `wxScrollerWindow` -> `wxWindows` -> ...) object size fit to parent `wxPanel` size?
I tried `Fit` method, but it doesn't work.
`OnInit` method:

```
bool MyApp::OnInit()
{
    wxFrame * win = new wxFrame(NULL, -1, _T("App"), wxPoint(300,300), wxSize(400,300), wxDEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE);
    wxPanel * panel = new wxPanel(win, -1);
    wxGrid * grid = new wxGrid(panel, -1, wxPoint(5,5), wxSize(300,200));
    grid->SetDefaultColSize(120);
    grid->SetDefaultRowSize(55);
    grid->SetRowLabelSize(55);
    grid->SetColLabelSize(25);
    grid->CreateGrid(2,6,wxGrid::wxGridSelectCells);
    grid->Fit();
    win->Show();
    return true;
}
```

`MyApp` inherits after `wxApp`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to use a [sizer](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_wxsizer.html):

```
wxSizer* sizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
// expand contents, add 5px border on all sides:
sizer->Add(grid,1,wxEXPAND|wxALL,5);
panel->SetSizer(sizer);
```

When the wxFrame is resized (as well as once it's shown for the first time), it automatically resizes its only (direct) child window (the panel) to fit its client size. The panel's sizer will then resize the grid.